# threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41616c80)

Tags: android

how to resolve this error? There appears to be only 1 line error when i run the app and it give me this error.

in the Main Activity i have made 3 Tabs layout

> Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HomeActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home")
            .setIndicator("HOME")//, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_home))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AboutActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("about")
            .setIndicator("ABOUT")//, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_about))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ContactActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("contact")
            .setIndicator("CONTACT")//,res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_contact))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    //set tab which one you want open first time 0 or 1 or 2
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);


}
```

}

This is my HomeActivity : which is my Tab 1

> HomeActivity

```
    public class HomeActivity extends Activity{
    TextView textView=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_call);
        getCallDetails();
    }
    private void getCallDetails() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
  /* Query the CallLog Content Provider */
        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, strOrder);
        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        sb.append("Call Log :");
        while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phNum = managedCursor.getString(number);
            String callTypeCode = managedCursor.getString(type);
            String strcallDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            Date callDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(strcallDate));
            String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
            String callType = null;
            int callcode = Integer.parseInt(callTypeCode);
            switch (callcode) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    callType = "Outgoing";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    callType = "Incoming";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    callType = "Missed";
                    break;
            }
            sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNum + " \nCall Type:--- "
                    + callType + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDate
                    + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
            sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
        }
        managedCursor.close();
        textView.setText(sb);
    }}
```

LOGCAT:

```
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41616c80)
```

Comment: Thank u ..
but it worked by just restarting :)